# Starlink and Mobile 4G: Route Google Meet over 4G

Tags: wan, load-balancer, google-meet

I have a Starlink satellite broadband WAN connection and a 4G mobile internet WAN connection.

Starlink is great for streaming and general internet but it drops out for a few seconds every hour due to an unavoidable obstruction.  The 4G connection is much slower but does not drop out.

I have a TPLink ER605 dual-WAN load balancer which can sit in front of the two connections.

What I want to do is route Google Meet traffic through the 4G connection (so that it doesn't freeze when the connection drops) and all other traffic through Starlink.

What would be the best way to do that?  If it relies on specifying the connection on certain ports, what ports do I need to assign to the 4G connection for Google Meet to work?

Comment: The load balancer decides that and it's not possible to set it as you want.